# Express middleware to inject content into <head>

Tags: node.js, express, middleware, node.js-connect

I'd like to create some Express middleware that injects content into the <head> part of every HTML document returned by the server. Is this possible or advisable?

Thanks!

Comment: This likely isn't a job for middleware, it's likely part of your template rendering.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>[Express Documentation/res.set](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.set)</strike>

Example:

```
app.all("*", function(req,res,next){
    res.set({
        "Myheader1":"Data1",
        "MyHeader2":"Data2"
    });
    next();
});
```

You should be using a templating engine like [JADE](http://jade-lang.com/), it allows layouts, you can define basic inheritance. I advise you to look at [Template inheritance](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#template-inheritance) from Jade documentation. I bet most templating languages have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ejs](http://ejs.co) as a view engine. Set the view engine in your `server.js` for example:

```
// Set the view engine to ejs (JS templating)
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

And in your views (.ejs) you can add your partials in this way:

```
<%include ../partials/head %>
```